# Joint Markov Chain (Two Correlated Markov Processes)

Tags: markov-process

I have two Markov Chains, and they exhibit some correlation between them. For instance, when Chain A moves to state i, there is a high likelihood that Chain B moves to state j. How would I go about modeling this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try hidden Markov models: modeling two chains as two observation sequence, and there is a hidden state sequence such that at certain state, chain A has high probability to be i while chain B has high probability to be j.